# Logs not being forwarded from Docker container to Graylog using gelf logging driver

Tags: docker, logging, graylog

I'm trying to figure out how to set up Graylog and collect logs from a test container using the gelf logging driver within the same Docker Compose file. The following is the content of my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:5.0.13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m"

  graylog:
    container_name: graylog
    image: graylog/graylog:5.1.1
    environment:
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 -- /docker-entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 12201:12201

  sender:
    container_name: sender
    build:
      context: ./sender
    depends_on:
      - graylog
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "tcp://192.168.0.12:12201"
        tag: "test"

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

The test container sends logs every 5 seconds, but they are not reaching Graylog. However, I can see the logs by running the command `docker logs sender`. As far as I understand, I shouldn't be able to see them there because they should be redirected to Graylog.

If the Graylog container is unreachable, the sender container reports it during startup, so it is definitely connecting to Graylog.

When I send logs using curl, they arrive in Graylog correctly.

What am I doing wrong?